# Writing a push method for an Array based implementation of ADT Stack

Tags: python, python-3.x, stack

I have to write a push method for an array-based stack which is implemented as an ArrayStack class.

```
import ctypes
from typing import Any

def _new_array(capacity: int) -> 'py_object_Array_<capacity>':
"""Return a new array with the specified capacity that stores
references to Python objects.
"""
if capacity < 1:
    raise ValueError('_new_array: capacity must be >= 1')
PyCArrayType = ctypes.py_object * capacity
a = PyCArrayType()
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i] = None
return a
```

Creating an instance of an ArrayStack uses the method _new_array() above

```
class ArrayStack:

def __init__(self, iterable=[]) -> None:
    
    self._n = 0  # number of elements stored in the stack
    self._items = _new_array(1)  # backing array

    for elem in iterable:
        self.push(elem)
```

Using the append method like follows: `self._items.append(x)`, gave me an error `'py_object_Array_1' object has no attribute 'append'` so I used `self._items[0]` but it does not push elements to the stack

```
 def push(self, x: Any) -> None:
    
    self._items[0] = x
```

Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

every time you do `self._items[0] = XYZ` you override the item that was stored in that index, 0.
What I suggest you do, is keep tracking on how many elements you have inserted so far. and just do `self._items[inserted] = x`.

```py
import ctypes
from typing import Any

def _new_array(capacity: int) -> 'py_object_Array_<capacity>':
    """Return a new array with the specified capacity that stores
    references to Python objects.
    """
    if capacity < 1:
        raise ValueError('_new_array: capacity must be >= 1')
    PyCArrayType = ctypes.py_object * capacity
    a = PyCArrayType()
    for i in range(len(a)):
        a[i] = None
    return a


class ArrayStack:
    def __init__(self, iterable=[]) -> None:
        self._items = _new_array(10)  # backing array
        self.capacity = len(self._items)
        self.inserted = 0

        for elem in iterable:
            self.push(elem)

    def push(self, x: Any) -> None:
        assert self.inserted < self.capacity, "Your array it larger than the capacity"
        self._items[self.inserted] = x
        self.inserted += 1
```

and then `stack = ArrayStack([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])` will be ok,because we set a stack of 10 elements, but `stack = ArrayStack([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11])` won't work  since you can't insert 11 elements into a 10-elements array.

also this section:

```py
    for i in range(len(a)):
        a[i] = None
```

is reduntand

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I'm sorry I didn't mention it earlier but would it be possible to achieve this without editing anything other than the push method only?

Comment: Yes, we can use the variable `self._n` you defined but it would be inefficient to look up `len(self._items)` every time.